# archlinux base installation not loading i915 intel driver

Tags: arch-linux, i915

I installed a latest archlinux iso(5.1.15 x86_64) on a Latitude E5570. There is a integrated intel GPU on board.
I followed the basic installation guide with only the `base` and `base-devel` packages. After reboot the cmdline loginprompt shows up and after like 5 seconds it disappears. I still can interact and reboot the machine normally but I just can't see anything. 
Googled around a bit and followed all the instructions explained for [intel graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Installation). Nothing worked so far.
I later realized that after running `modinfo i915` that there is no module installed.

The only thing that currently worked was blacklisting the kernel modules, but after blacklisting I wasn't able to start x11 as it requires the i915 module to be present.

Is there anything I am missing out here?

EDIT:

Some new informations: As soon as I plugin a monitor via Displayport or HDMI. The graphics are working